# REST CLIENT Proxy issue in Visual Studio Code

Tags: reactjs, rest-client

I am trying to send request using the REST CLIENT extension from the vsc and whenever I try to send the request and error pops up from the vsc stating that:

> The connection was rejected. Either the requested service isn’t running on the requested server/port, the proxy settings in vscode are misconfigured, or a firewall is blocking requests. Details: RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6969.

[image: Error Image]

I tried to check the proxy as well but there is no proxy enabled and the local host I am trying to use is also working and I have also launched the JSON server. so all these two are running simultaneously. I am unable to figure out how to fix this error. Checked the whole github issues page yet no positive response at all.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you read the error? Do you have a server running accepting connections at localhost at port 6969?

Comment: Yes , the server is running properly ( both the json and the react one).